# Problem with passing xml data to webservice .asmx

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have the ajax call to webservice jsonwebservice.asmx ,my datatype is xml, i have problem with passing data to webservice is thier any syntax problem

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false, 
                    url: "/blkseek2/JsonWebService.asmx/GetList",
                    datatype:"xml",
                    data: "keyword1="+keyword1+ "streetname="+address1+ "lat="+lat+  "lng="+lng+ "radius="+radius ,

```
             failure: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                     { ajaxError(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown); },
                success: function(xml) 
                 { ajaxFinish(xml); }



            });
            });
    });
```

Comment: What error message do you have? The property 'data' don't seem to be xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the data into xml.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: "/blkseek2/JsonWebService.asmx/GetList", datatype:"xml", data: "<?xml version='1.0'?><keyword1>"+keyword1+ "</keyword1><streetname>"+address1+ "</streetname><lat>"+lat+"</lat><lng>"+lng+ "</lng><radius>"+radius+"</radius>" ,
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,can write webmethod as shown below to catch the xml parameters passed from client side ajax call
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public XmlDocument GetList(string keyword1, string streetname, string lat, string lng, string radius)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc= CreateXML( keyword1,streetname,lat,lng,radius);
       // xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Vijay.EKO-03\Desktop\blkseek2\Block3.xml");


        return xmldoc;
        
    }